# How do for loops in Verilog execute?

Tags: for-loop, verilog

Do for loops in Verilog execute in parallel? I need to call a module several times, but they have to execute at the same time. Instead of writing them out one by one, I was thinking of using a for loop. Will it work the same?

Answer (score 4):

Verilog describes hardware, so it doesn't make sense to think in terms of executing loops or calling modules in this context.  If I understand the intent of your question correctly, you'd like to have multiple instantiations of the same module with distinct inputs and outputs.

To accomplish this you can use Verilog's [generate statements](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/verilog2k2.html) to generate the instantiations automatically.

You can also use the [auto_template functionality](http://www.veripool.org/wiki/verilog-mode/verilog-mode_veritedium#SEC17) in Emacs' excellent [verilog-mode](http://www.veripool.org/wiki/verilog-mode).  I prefer this approach as each instantiation appears explicitly in my source code and I find it easier to detect errors.

Comment: So you just put generate before the for loop? What happens if you don't?

Comment: The page I linked has an example of the usage.  If you don't wrap the loop and instantiation in a generate/endgenerate block your tool will complain -- try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

As jlf answered, you're looking for a generate statement.  You would use a for-loop to model combinational logic, such as going through all of the bits in a register and computing an output.  This would be in an always block or even an initial block in your testbench.